# Is there a way to filter out polygons/lines using geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, remote-sensing, classification

I am currently working on a project to digitize utility data, however my input layer is not classified. I am currently using length of the features to filter out unnecessary lines/polygons. Is there a way to filter using geometry?
[image: See image]

Comment: We're going to need more info on this. What do you want to filter? What file format is the data in?

Comment: Say for example filter out all the polygons with the shape : 'G3' (gas lines) or maybe with the particular legend: ----- -- G3 -- -----. Here I am working on a shape file (.shp). The project file format is .qgz.

Comment: Looks like you loaded a dxf/dwg file into QGIS - is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. However all those lines/polygons are in a single layer.

Comment: You are not trying to filter on geometry but on symbology then. If your shapefile is from DWG/DXF format you should have an attribute table with field that mimic all CAD propertie so you may be able to filter by layer and/or linetype (or any other CAD properties) to get what you want

Comment: I strongly suggest you get back to the people who provided the data and ask them use properly manage their data in CAD using layers. Or maybe a colleague with access to and knowledge in using CAD can help you out.

Comment: @J.R, in this particular example 'G3' is in the format of a poly-line. I need to filter out all the lines which are in the shape of 'G3'. Does it not mean the geometry then or is it symbology?

Comment: Geometry describe a line by it's coordinate, your G3 seem to relate to how a certain type of line are represented (in this case by a dash pattern and a G3 marking). If you got a file where each dash has been converted to a single line I think @Erik suggestion to get back to the people who provided the data is the best course of action. Also if you could share a picture if the attribute table it will be easier to understand what you are dealing with

Comment: @J.R in this case the symbology has been converted into poly-lines somehow. This was given to me by my manager, but he doesn't know about the exact source of the file. probably it was already in this single layer form when he received it. I will try to share the attribute table: https://imgur.com/a/sU7irBY Thank you!

Comment: I seem to recall that dwg converted to shapefiles will have a layer field with attributes for the different kinds of lines.  It may or may not be good enough for your purposes to use a selection/definition query on it.  If not you could perhaps find out which one of the layer attributes matches your interest by using the i button or by selecting one of the features, and then use that layer attribute for your selection/definition query.

Comment: looking at your attribute table (it would be better to edit your question to add the attribute table picture) it seem that you are out of luck (my initial suggestion was to find what linetype your G3 line use and filter using the Linetype field but it seem to be empty). Also the layer field being PDF_Geometry hint that your data was at one time in PDF format that may explain why it's hard to work with....